# How to run .sh script from usb in Terminal Recovery Mode?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, folders, mount

I am a novice user. I would like to run [MacUserGenerator](https://github.com/ninxsoft/MacUserGenerator) exported shell script to create an account on a brand new iMac without manually doing this in the set up process. Not sure if this possible? The bash shell script is on my USB stick: `usbName/Install/Scripts/createAccount.sh`

Steps Taken:

1. Boot into Recovery Mode/Single User Mode
2. Execute the following:

   ```
   diskutil list
   diskutil mountDisk both usb stick and internal HD
   cd /Volumes/usbName/Install/Scripts/
   sh createAccount.sh
   ```

---

```
    fsck –fy
    mount –uw /
    mount_msdos /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes
    cd Install/Scripts
    sh createAccount.sh
```

3. The above spits out:

   ```
   Print: Entry, ":_writers_UserCertificate", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":_writers_hint", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":_writers_jpegphoto", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":_writers_passwd", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":_writers_picture", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":_writers_realname", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":_writers_UserCertificate", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":authentication_authority", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":generateduid", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":gid", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":home", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":name", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":passwd", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":realname", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":shell", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":uid", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   Print: Entry, ":ShadowHashData", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   sed: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist: No such file or directory
   sed: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist: No such file or directory
   chmod: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist: No such file or directory
   Print: Entry, ":jpegphoto", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist
   sed: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist: No such file or directory
   sed: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist: No such file or directory
   sed: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist: No such file or directory
   sed: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist: No such file or directory
   sed: /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/esoadmin.plist: No such file or directory
   Print: Entry, ":DidSeeCloudSetup", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Users/esoadmin/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant.plist
   Print: Entry, ":DidSeeSiriSetup", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Users/esoadmin/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant.plist
   Print: Entry, ":DidSeeTouchIDSetup", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Users/esoadmin/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant.plist
   Print: Entry, ":LastSeenCloudProductVersion", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Users/esoadmin/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant.plist
   Print: Entry, ":LastSeenBuddyBuildVersion", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Users/esoadmin/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant.plist
   Print: Entry, ":DidSeePrivacy", Does Not Exist
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Users/esoadmin/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant.plist
   mkdir: /Users/esoadmin/Library/Preferences: Read-only file system
   chmod: /Users/esoadmin: No such file or directory
   chown: esoadmin: illegal user name
   chmod: /Users/esoadmin/Library: No such file or directory
   chown: esoadmin: illegal user name
   chmod: /Users/esoadmin/Library/Preferences: No such file or directory
   chown: esoadmin: illegal user name
   ```

What is going wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Why is this expected to work from Recovery Mode?  The utility you're using does not describe that as a use-case.

Comment: Can you please either add the script or (as it's too big for that) put it into a gist on Github (or similar) and share the link? I assume that the script is not meant to run in recovery mode (where the paths to system files are different).

Comment: The two posts below have a lot of clarification questions so right now the question is too unclear to get good answers. Can you please edit your question and address the issues raised below?

Answer (score 1):

My friend, at first glance you are going to have a problem with the file hierarchy, given it is not the normal volume and its structure which the script has made presumptions to use.

Your root file system in recovery mode is a different volume and not the normal one used in normal use.

You will likely be better off in normal mode, or booting to single user mode and then running the script.

F.

Comment: I have booted up in single user mode, however I still end up getting the same spit out as mentioned as above.

Answer (score 1):

Are these two scripts?  Did you run both?  I've lost context.  If you typed these commands in at the terminal should see the commands in the output, but I haven't been able to find the commands.
You should place your usb stick in your machine before booting.

I think the problem is that the commands you are attempting to use don't run in the bare single user mode.

Let's assume you are booted in single user mode. You need to do next:

```
fsck –fy
mount –uw /
```

# diskutil mountDisk both usb stick and internal HD

In single user mode, your startup disk is now in read/write mode.  You should place your usb stick in your machine before booting. In 10.4.11, when booting in single user mode, the flash drive was automatically mounted. Let's assume it still is. Things may have changed.  You may need to follow these instructions.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573

Let's see what's mounted:

```
diskutil list
```

I suspect that you need to startup more of macOS.  This worked for me in 10.4.11.  I'm looking around to see what is the case now...

```
sh /etc/rc
```

See this page for later OS's
http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/25/change-admin-password-mac/
read the section around this command.
 #3 launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist

```
cd /Volumes/usbName/Install/Scripts/
```

Is your script written for the sh shell? Documentation indicates it's written for bash

```
bash createAccount.sh
```

Your going to have to put some debugging in your script to see what is going on.    You can try:

```
 bash -v createAccount.sh
```

Comment: Excellent answer, and I concur with the recommendations here.